# NPC Moving through the walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a tactical RPG and I've set walls in order to prevent the NPC to move outside the game's area. However, the NPC is moving through the walls. He has a rigidbody, a box collider attached to him and he is triggered. Besides, the use gravity option and is kinematic are marked as well. The walls have a rigidbody and a box collider. They are not triggered.

I'm using this code to move the NPC:

```
targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x + 3;
targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z;
this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity);
```

I've read that this way of moving could be causing the issue. Is that right?

Comment: You probably want to use some kind of navigation system and move your NPC by giving it a target which results in calculating a path and then following it. [This should help](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html)

Comment: If you're using rigidbodies on your game object then you should really never touch the `transform.position`, and leave that all to the rigidbody to handle. You can tell your objects how to move with `Rigidbody.MovePosition` or `Rigidbody.velocity` :)

Comment: @MaxPlay I don't know how to use navigation system. I think it would be much easier if I knew how to use it.

Comment: @JackJohn the link I gave you is the official documentation of Unity and has even a link to tutorials for the topic. This should be sufficient to learn how to use it. Just read more than just the page I gave you but also the subpages and links.

Comment: @MaxPlay That link is awesome, it has everything regarding this topic. I'm currently reading it and trying to find a way that I could use in my game. Thanks for that.

Comment: @jake I've converted this line ```this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity)``` to  ```myRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + targetPosition * velocity)``` and now the character is flying away. I just want him to move towards. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) attached to your GameObject, you should use that to move it, not the [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html), since it's the Rigidbody that talks to the physics engine and is in charge of syncing the position. In this scenario the appropriate function should be [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generics;

public class NPC: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(rb.position + new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Since we're using the physics to move the GameObject, the logic must be placed in [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html).

Comment: I've changed this line ```this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity)```  to ``` myRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity))``` and the NPC still walks through the walls.

Comment: Check your Collider and Rigidbody settings then, and remember to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to make the movement speed framerate indipendent.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.